# Do Java records support "with" syntax?

Tags: java, java-14, java-record

Java 14 brings records, which are a great addition seen in many functional languages:

*Java:*

```java
public record Vehicle(String brand, String licensePlate) {}
```

*ML:*

```ml
type Vehicle = 
  {
    Brand : string
    LicensePlate : string
  }
```

In ML languages, it is possible to "update" a record by creating a copy with a few values changed:

```ml
let u = 
  {
    Brand = "Subaru"
    LicensePlate = "ABC-DEFG"
  }

let v =
  {
    u with 
      LicensePlate = "LMN-OPQR"
  }

// Same as: 
let v = 
  {
    Brand = u.Brand
    LicensePlate = "LMN-OPQR"
  }
```

Is this possible in Java 14?

Comment: Go to Java 16. They have some nice changes. And the answer is no

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Just curious, did you mean "nice changes" in relevance to the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is: Not yet.

Comment: @naman no. Java 16 allows defining the record closer to where you need to use it.

Comment: @lino that is not good advice.

Comment: Seems like, my understanding of the `with` pattern was not correct and the precise answer to the question would be as mentioned by @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen.

Comment: This is a good candidate for a [JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0).

Comment: Use lombok. It supports that since Java 7

Comment: @texasbruce Don’t use Lombok. It does very nasty tricks under the hood

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It's called compiler plugin

Comment: There is a concept of "withers" described in this exploratory document: [Functional transformation of immutable objects](https://github.com/openjdk/amber-docs/blob/master/eg-drafts/reconstruction-records-and-classes.md)

Comment: @texasbruce just don’t. You make your programs less future proof.

Comment: Not yet, but it is under discussion.

Comment: Lack of this feature makes Records much less compelling and will result in yet more Lombok adoption (to be clear - I avoid Lombok but understand why people use it).  I thought Records would see a major reduction in the usage of Lombok and even help drive adoption of the next LTS.  Woe is me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java does not include this functionality. Though, you could create a utility method that takes in a different license plate value:

```java
public static Vehicle withLicensePlate(Vehicle a, String newLicensePlate) {
    return new Vehicle(a.brand, newLicensePlate);
}
```

Used like so:

```java
Vehicle a = new Vehicle("Subaru", "ABC-DEFG");
Vehicle b = Vehicle.withLicensePlate(a, "LMN-OPQR");
```

This would give you a similar result to what you were attempting using the "with" tag. And you can use this as a way to update the record.

Comment: The correct declaration would be `public Vehicle(Vehicle a, String newLicensePlate) { this(a.brand, newLicensePlate); }` but it’s a bad pattern anyway. The constructor’s parameter types don’t indicates whether the argument is a new brand or new license plate and supporting constructors for both elements doesn’t work at all when both have the same type. A cleaner approach would be to add a *method* to the record, like `public Vehicle withLicensePlate(String newLicensePlate) { return new Vehicle(brand, newLicensePlate); }` which can be used like `Vehicle b = a.withLicensePlate("LMN-OPQR");`

Comment: @Holger I am not very used to ML, and as informed by OP the `with` pattern is something that's expected out of the box of records without the introduction of any new method. I almost formulated a similar design to that of your proposal [here](https://github.com/fortybits/a-bit-of-java/blob/bits/src/main/java/edu/bit/WithPatternInRecords.java), but in my (now deleted) answer I couldn't really match up to the OP's expectation I believe.

Comment: @Holger suggestion is what would be achieved automatically using `with`. It's disappointing Java doesn't support this; when a PL has "records", this feature is usually assumed.

Comment: @Naman I know that the OP asked for an automatism that unfortunately doesn’t exist (yet?). I just responded to the answer which suggested a constructor whereas a method would be much better.

Comment: @Holger just in case you are not _yet_ tired of me pinging you for questions that simply only you can respond to (imho), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075419/which-part-of-the-jls-specifies-that-you-cant-cast-from-list-extends-listsup) is one

Comment: FYI - I've written a library that generates "with"ers for Java 16 records: https://github.com/Randgalt/record-builder